# Using textvariable for a Tkinter (or ttk) LabelFrame

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update the label of a Tkinter `LabelFrame` widget.

For a `Label` widget, this can be done using the `textvariable` attribute, to which one can assign a `StringVar`.

I want to do the same thing, but for a `LabelFrame`

```
self.labelText = StringVar()
self.selectionFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, textvariable=self.labelText)

(...)

if A:
     self.labelText.set("LabelA")
elif B:
     self.labelText.set("LabelB")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Neither the Tkinter LabelFrame nor the ttk LabelFrame support associating a variable with the widget.

If what you're really asking is how can you change the label, then you can use the `configure` method:

```
self.selectionFrame.configure(text="hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, Bryan - this is definitely the more direct approach. There's no point in storing the StringVar separately.
For the record, the solution for my code exaple would be: `self.selectionFrame.configure(text="hello")`

Answer (score 1):

I just found some kind of a solution - using the `labelwidget` attribute to supply a separate `Label` object which uses the underlying `StringVar`:

```
self.labelText = StringVar()
self.labelWidget = Label(self, textvariable=self.labelText)
self.selectionFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, labelwidget=self.labelWidget)
```

This way, I can update the `labelText` to change the label of the LabelFrame

```
self.labelText.set("New Label")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a problem to set a new label text due to text length.
So, I recommend that define a width of `labelwidget` as mentioned below:

```
self.labelWidget = Label(self, textvariable=self.labelText, width = 20)
```